# How do can conditionally add/remove an attribute in a view in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

Sometimes you need to conditionally add/remove an attribute on an HTML element, rather than just conditionally changing the attribute's value.

An example of this would be when disabling a `button` element. To do that you need to add the `disabled` attribute. You can't then just set the `disabled` attribute to `false` to re-enable the element, you need to remove the whole attribute.

At the moment, if I want to do this in the view I am doing:

```html
  <aura:if isTrue="{! v.canMovePrevious}">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.PrevPage}">Prev</button>
    <aura:set attribute="else">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.PrevPage}" disabled="">Next</button>
    </aura:set>
  </aura:if>
```

This seems extremely clumsy, repeating the whole markup for the element is horrible.

Is there a way I can do this in the view that is cleaner and avoids repeating the markup ?

(I'm sure I could do this in code in the controller, but I really don't want my controller to have to be messing around in the view when I can avoid it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use something like `disabled="{!v.disabled}"` in your code. That's how the `ui:button` works:

```
<aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<button disabled="{!v.disabled}"/>
```

See the source code here:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/button/button.cmp#L73

Comment: I was all ready to comment and say that wouldn't work, as `default="false"` will not work in HTML. However I checked and using it in Aura markup does indeed work. When the framework parses the markup it removes the `default="false"` from the HTML that actually gets rendered in the browser.

Comment: The code that performs this bit of magic is in https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/aura/html/htmlHelper.js (see the code using `isSpecialBoolean`).